# Rspec / shoulda: testing, that a custom validator is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda

I have a custom validator (located in app/validators/uri_validator.rb) which is used in:

```
validates :link, uri: true
```

How do I specify this in my specs?

Ideally I would like to have a one-line call, such as:

```
it { should validate_uri_of(:link) }
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use the `allow_value` matcher, although not ideal it can work in some circumstances.

```
it { should allow_value(value_which_is_valid).for(:link) }
it { should_not allow_value(value_which_is_invalid).for(:link) }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use factory girl to build a model object with invalid data and one with valid data and call the be_valid matcher.

```
#factory girl
build(:model, link: valid_uri).should be_valid
build(:model, link: invalid_uri).should_not be_valid
```

Comment: I try not to hit the database during testing when it is possible.

Comment: Using factory girl with `build` does not hit the database, it creates an unsaved model.